# php strtotime function showing 1 hour more

Tags: php, xampp, strtotime, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert **1355657846 and 1355677646** unix timestamp to **Y-M-D H:i:s format**.
The problem is in H:i:s . It should be 
**11:37:24 and 17:07:26** respectively but it is showing 12:37:24 and 18:07:26.

```
<?php

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s','1355657846');//2012-12-16 12:37:26,must be 11:37:26

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s','1355677646');//2012-12-16 18:07:26,must be 17:07:26

?>
```

It should be 11:37 and 17:07 because I checked it in [unix timestamp conversion](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)

and also **it is the time I had received mail in gmail account**. And I got these unix timestamp from gmail( using php imap function...$overview->udate)

I am testing this on local xampp server.
Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong here?

PS: I checked [related question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303970/php-strtotime-function-wrong-by-1-hour), but here I want to convert timestamp to datetime, which I think should be constant irrespective of timezone.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the TimeZone setting.  Learn about PHP [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and make sure your local time zone matches the timezone you really want.  All Unix Timestamps are the same world-wide.  But the local DATETIME values vary around the globe.  This article may be visible to you (hope so):

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/A_201-Handling-date-and-time-in-PHP-and-MySQL.html

Best regards, ~Ray

Answer (score 0):

It is definetily the timezone setting in your local web server.

Check the php.ini for date.timezone value.
It also may be overridden by htaccess file or you PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime was included once DateTime was created. The parsing is dependant of the server default timezone.

If you want get your date with the good timezone, there are two ways :

```
default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');//for example
```

or :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$timestamp,new DateTimezone('Europe/Paris'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s);
```

you can find more informations [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/A_201-Handling-date-and-time-in-PHP-and-MySQL.html) .